# unable get json from url

Tags: java, android, json

i have to create simple login page  where after entering username and password we click to submit button. when we click on submit button then it goes to server and check the username and other information if the info matches then it moves to next activity otherwise nothing will happen . below is my code . i dont know how to do after getting response from the server.

```
package com.example.dev_1.myapplication;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.net.Uri
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.JarURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.sql.Connection;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  Button button;
    String connectionString, params;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
                    String userNameString = username.getText().toString();
                    String passwordString = password.getText().toString();
                    String url = "http://122.160.78.189:82/androidserver/LoginSalesPerson";
                        String params = null;
                        try {
                        params = "user=" + URLEncoder.encode(userNameString, "UTF-8") + "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(passwordString, "UTF-8") + "&appVersion=1.26";
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;
                    new Mytask().execute(url, params);
                }
              }
        }));
    }
    private void checkLogin(String result) throws JSONException {
        String url = "http://122.160.78.189:82/androidserver/LoginSalesPerson";
        JSONArray user = null;
        try{
            // Creating new JSON Parser
            ///JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            // Getting JSON from URL
           // JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            if (result != null)
            {
                //JSONObject emp=(new JSONObject(url).getJSONObject("username"));
            JSONObject emp = new JSONObject(result.toString());
            String username=emp.getString("userName");
            //String  empspassword=emp.getString("password");
                String str="username:"+username;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
             intent.putExtra("username", str);
              startActivity(intent);}
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //   EditText usernameString = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        //  String str = usernameString.getText().toString();
        // if (sharedPreferences.equals(str)) {
        //  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        //  intent.putExtra("username", str);
//startActivity(intent);
// To retrieve value from shared preference in another activity
        //   sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
        //         "sharedPrefName", 0);
        // id = sharedPreferences.getString("key_name", "defaultvalue");
    class Mytask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        // Runs in UI before background thread is called
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            setProgressBarVisibility(true);
            // Do something like display a progress bar
        }
        // This is run in a background thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            return getFromServer(params[0], params[1]);
        }
        // This runs in UI when background thread finishes
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                checkLogin(result);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
   public String getFromServer(String connectionString, String params) {
            String response = "";
            try {
                // android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
                URL url = new URL(connectionString);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                con.setConnectTimeout(10 * 1000); //10 Seconds
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(params.getBytes().length));
                con.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
                con.setUseCaches(false);
                con.setDoInput(true);
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(params);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
                InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
                response = read(is);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                return response;
            }
        }
        private String read(InputStream in) {
            BufferedReader reader;
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                return response.toString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: didi you get the responce

Comment: i get the response from server ,

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The question is too vague and it's hard to tell where you're running into a problem. Is it hitting the exception catch? Could you paste the logcat showing the exception if so? Do you know what line of code there's a problem with?

Comment: what is the result that you get from the server

Comment: i got the user information like user name , password ,id etc

Comment: the problem is i dont know how to do json from url and store it using share prefrence and then move to next activity

Comment: the problem is in checkLogin method